# parse javascript date to elixir format

Tags: date, datetime, elixir

I have some saved dates in JavaScript using `new Date()` that looks like:

"Sun Feb 24 2019 14:44:20 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)"

I'm trying to parse these to Elixir `DateTime`; I didn't find anything in "timex" that can help and I already know that I can use `DateTime.from_iso8601` but for dates saved using `new Date().toISOString()` but what i need is to parse the above string.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use elixir binary pattern matching to extract the date parts and parse using Timex's `RFC1123` format. The RFC1123 is the format `e.g Tue, 05 Mar 2013 23:25:19 +0200`. Run `h Timex.Format.DateTime.Formatters.Default` in iex to see other formats.

```
iex> date_string = "Sun Feb 24 2019 14:44:20 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)"

iex> <<day_name::binary-3,_,month_name::binary-3,_,day::binary-2,_,year::binary-4,_,time::binary-8,_::binary-4,offset::binary-5,_,rest::binary>> = date_string

iex> Timex.parse("#{day_name}, #{day} #{month_name} #{year} #{time} #{offset}", "{RFC1123}")

iex> {:ok, #DateTime<2019-02-24 14:44:20+02:00 +02 Etc/GMT-2>}
```

Pattern matching:
The binary-size are in byte sizes. 1 byte == 1 character. For instance to get 
 3-character `day_name` the size is 3. Underscores (_) is used to pattern match the spaces in the date format

**Updated answer to use `binary-size` rather than bitstring-size for simplicity**

Answer (score 1):

> I didn't find anything in "timex" that can help

The [Timex Parsing docs](https://github.com/bitwalker/timex/blob/master/docs/Parsing.md) say that you can use `strftime` sequences, e.g `%H:%M:%S`, for parsing.  Here's a list of [strftime characters](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/strftime/) and what they match.

Here's a format string that I think *should* work on javascript Dates:

```
  def parse_js_date() do
    Timex.parse!("Sun Feb 24 2019 14:44:20 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)", 
                 "%a %b %d %Y %H:%M:%S GMT%z (%Z)",
                 :strftime)
  end
```

Unfortunately, `%Z` doesn't want to match the time zone name, which causes `Timex.parse!()` to spit out an error.  It looks like `%Z` in Elixir only matches one word, e.g. a timezone abbreviation `EET`. Therefore, my simple, clean solution is spoiled.

What you *can do* is chop off the time zone name before parsing the date string:

```
def parse_js_date_string() do

    [date_str|_tz_name] = String.split(
        "Sun Feb 24 2019 14:44:20 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)",
        " (", 
        parts: 2
    )

    Timex.parse!(date_str,
                 "%a %b %d %Y %H:%M:%S GMT%z",
                :strftime)
  end
```

In iex:

```
~/elixir_programs/my$ iex -S mix
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]
Compiling 1 file (.ex)
Interactive Elixir (1.6.6) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)

iex(1)> My.parse_js_date_string()
#DateTime<2019-02-24 14:44:20+02:00 +02 Etc/GMT-2>

iex(2)>
```